# How to delete text from cursor pos to next occurrence of 'xyz' during Notepad++ macro

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'm recording a macro in Np++, and at a particular point in the recording I need to remove all the text from where the cursor currently is up to and including a particular string (say 'xyz') - this string never changes - it's constant every time the macro is run.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aww man - talk about rubber ducking my own answer. Sorry about that.

In the Np++ Search menu I discovered

> Select All Between Matching Braces (Ctrl+Alt+B)

It also turns out that there will never be a brace in the text I am wanting to select. So in my macro I recorded the following key sequence...

```
<other macro stuff>
{
Ctrl+F
   xyz
   Find Next
   Close
RightArrow
}
Ctrl+Alt+B
Backspace
<more macro stuff>
```

Thanks for being my sounding board SOF